How to start a chapter with numbering as 9.1
My chapter in a book is numbered 9. My first section (introduction) should be numbered as 9.1 and so on. My first table should be numbered as Table 9.1 and so on. Is there any method to do so in Latex?
the MWE is:
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{color,soul}  
\begin{document}  
\title{Machine Learning based }  
\begin{abstract}  
\end{abstract}  
\section{Introduction} %should be 9.1  
\begin{table} %should be table 9.1  
\end{document}  


\setcounter{chapter}{8} before \chapter{...}.

Please tell us which document class you employ.

Please make your code compile. As provided, it will fail with an error. If I fix that, it doesn't include any numbers for tables or figures whatsoever.

That is the default with the book and report classes. If that's not what you are using, please post a minimal working example.

Shouldn't this be a comment rather than an answer?

@cfr Perhaps...meh.

Preparation
This is how to prepare a minimised example (MWE) to include in future questions. You want something like this:
\documentclass{llncs} 
\begin{document}  
\section{a} 
\begin{table} %should be table 9.1  
  \caption{s}
\end{table}
\section{Introduction} %should be 9.2 
\begin{table} %should be table 9.1  
  \caption{s}
\end{table}
\end{document}

This is minimal: it doesn't include anything extraneous to the problem such as unneeded packages, a title or abstract.
This compiles: it doesn't leave a group open at the end of the document.
This demonstrates the issue: it includes a table or figure in at least two sections, both of which have \caption to ensure they get the numbers we want to format differently.
Answer
To include the section number in the format of table and figure numbers, we redefine \thetable and \thefigure:
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

However, this will not make the first figure in section 9 9.1 unless there are no figures in the first eight sections. To achieve that, we want to tell LaTeX to reset the counters at the starts of sections:
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

If you only want the chapter number but not the section number
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

and don't make the numbers relative to the sections in this case.
To persuade LaTeX this is chapter nine, you can use
\setcounter{section}{8}
\chapter{}

or
\setcounter{chapter}{9}

but you may have trouble with runningheads in this case.
Complete code with comments for other options:
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs} 
% the class uses but does not define this
\makeatletter
\let\@chapapp\chaptername
\makeatother
% if you don't want the section number in table/figure numbers
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
% if you want the sec number in table/figure numbers
% \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
% \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
% if you need additional sectioning commands, follow this pattern
% \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
% if you want numbering reset for each section, uncomment
% \counterwithin{table}{section}
% \counterwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}  
\setcounter{chapter}{8}% make this 9 if you are not using \chapter i.e if that will be added later
\chapter{ninth}
\section{a} % should be 9.1
\begin{table} %should be table 9.1.1 (or 9.1?)
  \caption{s}
\end{table}
\section{Introduction} %should be 9.2  
\begin{table} %should be table 9.1.1 (or 9.2?)
  \caption{s}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The class seems buggy as it uses \@chapapp without defining it and loads only article.cls which doesn't provide it.

This works, thank you. only that the introduction should be 9.1 instead of 9. related works should be 9.2 and so on.

@junaids Sorry, I don't understand. I thought the table should be 9.1 i.e. the first table in the ninth section. What is 9 if not the section number? And how can the table be 9.1? Or do you just want everything prefaced by 9 i.e. you don't want number-within at all?

9 is my chapter number in the book where other chapters will be from different authors. So the sections should be 9.1, 9.2, and so on

@junaids So you don't want number-within? How should the figure numbers go, for example? Should they go 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 or 9.1.1, 9.1.2, 9.2.1 or what?

@junaids See edit. I included code for both schemes, so you can uncomment what you need.

working perfectly now.
